# Contour plot of a multivariate function

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a multivariate function

[image]

X is (2, 1), A(100, 2), and b is (100, 1).

How can I plot the contour plot of it in python? for a simple case like Z = X^2 + Y^2 I have this code, but I don't think it can work for my problem.

```
x, y = np.linspace(-3, 3, 400), np.linspace(-3, 3, 400)

XX, YY = np.meshgrid(x, y)

Z = (XX ** 2 + YY ** 2)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.contour(XX, YY, Z)
```

How can I plot contour of my function?

Answer (score 0):

I assumed that in the pictured formula `x` is the same as `X`, which represents the coordinates of a point in a 2D plane.

Then, with `np.meshgrid` you create the usual grid of coordinates over which evaluating the function, `xx` and `yy`. At this points, you need to combine them into a matrix `X` of 2 rows (representing x and y coordinates) and as many columns as necessary.

Finally, you evaluate the function over each column of `X`.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create example data
x = y = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
A = np.stack([np.cos(x), np.sin(x * y)]).T
b = np.cbrt(x * y)
print("A.shape = ", A.shape)
print("b.shape = ", b.shape)

# define the function
f = lambda X: np.linalg.norm(b - A @ X, 2)**2

# creates the coordinates over which the function
# will be evaluated
x = y = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 200)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)
# assemble the coordinates into a "vector of coordinates"
X = np.stack([xx, yy]).reshape(2, -1)
print("X.shape = ", X.shape)
# apply the function f on each pair of coordinates
Z = np.apply_along_axis(f, 0, X).reshape(xx.shape)
print("Z.shape = ", Z.shape)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
c = ax.contourf(xx, yy, Z)
fig.colorbar(c)
plt.show()
```

[image]